# Is there any prevention methods for removing `IsTrial` and trivially cracking WinRT applications?

Tags: javascript, licensing, windows-runtime, reverse-engineering, windows-store

I read an article about [reverse engineering](http://justinangel.net/ReverseEngineerWin8Apps) windows 8 applications. One of the most concerning things is how easily they are modified, yet how Microsoft also includes licensing in them.

Of particular note is Javsscript(though C# is also vulnerable with IL-rebuilding). They provide the function `LicenseInformation.IsTrial()`. However, as stated in the article, if you change a few permissions, you can directly edit the javascript and just replace `IsTrial` with `false`.

This article was made in a very early(first) public release of Windows 8 though. What measures have they done to prevent modifications from happening in the current release version? Should Javascript applications be regarded as impossible to monetize?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

App packages are signed and are periodically checked for tampering.  Windows will not start a packaged app that has been flagged as having been tampered with (modifying files in the package is a form of tampering).

The ["App packages and deployment"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh464929.aspx) documentation page states:

> All packages must be signed with a trusted signature. This enables Windows to confirm the identity of the signer and verify that the contents of the package haven't been tampered with. Windows won't deploy an unsigned package.

The ["Signing an app package"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br230260.aspx) documentation page states:

> If any files in an installed package are modified, signing verification might prevent the app from launching.

That said, there's no *technical* restriction preventing someone from cracking open the app package and building a new, modified package. To do this, a developer license is required.  At this point, though, it's no different from any other program that a user can download and install.

Comment: It actually is fairly hard to get ahold of the original .appx package(requires using Fiddler to get the URL)... I believe it's also possible to just take all the files from the windows store app directory though and repackage it from there. So basically, it's not super easy, but definitely possible for anyone familiar with developing Windows Store apps?

Comment: Also, what about round-tripping a .Net assembly? This is a bit off-topic, but would signing it help at all?

Comment: @Earlz: I haven't done that, so I don't know from personal experience, but I would think it would be possible to repackage the contents in a new app. I would guess that it would be fairly simple to make this a bit harder, e.g. by testing the validity of the app package yourself in code. However, if the user has the app on his machine, then it's certainly possible for him to disassemble it and put it back together as he sees fit (this is easier in JavaScript and .NET, but it's still true in C++ to a degree). I don't see why things would be different for Windows Store apps than for desktop apps.

Comment: I just find it odd as most licensing schemes don't just have a single line of code or a single function to disable, they instead usually have many many subtle checks making it difficult to crack. It seems like people pass over the fact that Windows Store packages are just a zip file with executable code